# I need to run a function if the URL has a specific string that can also come up as part of another string using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, url

I need to write a function to perform an action only if the URL has a specific string.  The issue that I am finding is that the string can come up in multiple instances as part of another string.  I need the function to run when the string is ONLY "?page=1".  What I am finding is that the function is also being run when the string contains a string like "?page=10" , "?page=11" , "?page=12" , etc...  I only need it to be done if the string is "?page=1" - that's it.  How do I do that?  I've tried a couple of different ways, but it does not work.  Any help is appreciated.  Here is the latest code that I have used that is close...but no cigar.

```
var location = window.location.href; 
if (location.indexOf("?page=1") > -1){
//Do something
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?page` is a GET parameter. It doesn't necessarily have to be first in the URL string. I suggest you properly decode the GET params and then base your logic on that. Here's how you can do that:

```
function unparam(qs) {
    var params = {},
        e,
        a = /\+/g,
        r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        d = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(a, " ")); };

    while (e = r.exec(qs)) {
        params[d(e[1])] = d(e[2]);
    }

    return params;
}

var urlParams = unparam(window.location.search.substring(1));

if(urlParams['page'] == '1') {
    // code here
}
```

Alternatively, a regex with word boundaries would have worked:

```
if(/\bpage=1\b/.test(window.location.search)) {
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(location .indexOf("?page=1&") != -1 || (location .indexOf("?page=1") + 7 == i.length) ) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the character immediately following the string "?page=1" in the url. If it's a digit,you don't have a match otherwise you do. You could trivially do something like this:

```
  var index = location.indexOf("?page=1"); //Returns the index of the string
  var number = location.charCodeAt(index+x); //x depends on the search string,here x = 7
  //Unicode values for 0-9 is 48-57, check if number lies within this range
```

Now that you have the Unicode value of the next character, you can easily deduce if the url contains the string you require or not. I hope this points you in the right direction.